# How to make widget background same as window background ,,transparent,,

Tags: python, widget

I don,t know how to make widget bg transparent. I don,t want to see my desk throught it just window background image i set.

```
from tkinter import *
okno = Tk() 
tlo = PhotoImage(file='C:\\Prywatny Backup\\Kalkulejtor 
       2.2\\shinji.png'
label = Label(
okno,
image=tlo
)
label.place(x=0, y=0)
guzik1 = Button(okno,
            text='1',
            command=klik1,
            font=("Arial",30),
            height=(1),
            width=(2),
              #i want to make this button have same background as i 
   set 
               to the window eirlier
            )
   guzik1.place(x=60,y=160)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.